# Injecting Autowired Variable

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have the following service class :

```
    @Component
    public class ABC {


      @Autowired private SomeClass assumeRoles; 

      @Override
      public @NotNull Optional<Something> translate(int id) {
             // Some Code
             SomeClass result = assumeRoles.getRole(id);

      }
   }
```

Now I want to write Junit for my class, I don't want `Role.getRole(id)` to be get called, instead of that I want to mock this function call, with some dummy value.

So can I do that?

I have my Junit class as

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class ABCTest {

      @InjectMocks
      private ABC test = new ABC();

      @Mock
      private SomeClass assumeRoles;


      @Test
      public void testTranslate() {

        ABC result =  test.translate(id);    
      }

    }
```

Comment: Yes! you can mock that you using mockito

Comment: @VinayPrajapati i tried that using above code but still call is begin made

Comment: what is assumeRoles?

Comment: To mock static methods, you have to use power Mockito.

Comment: that's not a static method @GauravGupta

Comment: `Role.getRole(id)` is a static method which is to be mocked

Comment: please put a better code as of now it unclear. `Role` is capital case and is a variable but injected is assumeRoles variable in test. fix it all up.

Comment: Remove the `= new ABC();`. It's not necessary; Mockito will instantiate the class for you.

Comment: @GauravGupta How do you know that `Role.getRole(id)` is a static method? Nothing in the question above says that has to be static.

Answer (score 1):

You have already marked `SomeClass assumeRoles` as `@Mock`, you can mock the `Role.getRole(id);` statement as follows.

```
Mockito.when(assumeRoles.getRole(Mockito.any(id))).thenReturn(someResult);
```

I have answered the question after making some assumptions, I suggest you to improve the code snippet you have provided with correct variable and class names.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, `field injection` is not recommended by the spring team explained at here: https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/

So, you'd better mark the field `final` if required: `private final SomeClass assumeRoles;`, then provide a constructor like this:

```
public ABC(SomeClass assumeRoles) {
  this.assumeRoles = assumeRoles;
}
```

In this way, it would be easier to pass the dummy `SomeClass` to the constructor to get an instance of `ABC`.